# How to share data between all process in Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to search for pre-defined list of keywords in a given article and increment the score by 1 if keyword is found in article. I want to use multiprocessing since pre-defined list of keyword is very large - 10k keywords and number of article is 100k.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157367/how-to-share-data-between-python-processes) question but it does not address my question.

I tried this implementation but getting `None` as result.

```
keywords = ["threading", "package", "parallelize"]

def search_worker(keyword):
    score = 0
    article = """
    The multiprocessing package also includes some APIs that are not in the threading module at all. For example, there is a neat Pool class that you can use to parallelize executing a function across multiple inputs."""

   if keyword in article:
        score += 1
    return score
```

I tried below two method but getting three `None` as result.

Method1:

```
 pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
 result = [pool.apply(search_worker, args=(keyword,)) for keyword in keywords]
```

Method2:

```
result = pool.map(search_worker, keywords)
print(result)
```

**Actual output:** [None, None, None]

**Expected output:** 3

I think of sending the worker the pre-defined list of keyword and the article all together, but I am not sure if I am going in right direction as I don't have prior experience of multiprocessing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't use ElasticSearch as your search engine?

Comment: I am not sure how to do this using ElasticSearch. I want to calculate the confidence score for each article against a list of keywords and index article along with confidence score.

Comment: ElasticSearch Can easily do this! You should really try

Comment: There are different solutions for your case. One, you can have a shared memory, like a database. Redis is really simple and works very well. Dependning of your scale plan and planned complexity, adopt some map-reduce technique.

Comment: Your code works just fine-ish when I run it (python3.5).  (I get [1, 1, 1], you just need a global count or to sum the result). Did you remember to run **method 1** and **method 2** using `if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Comment: @e.s., Thanks, it's working with `if __name__ == '__main__'. Any idea, how to increment the score on the fly and return the final score only. Is it possible to pass article instead of list-of-keywords to worker method?

Comment: @e.s. Is it possible to pass article instead of list-of-keywords or both article and pre-defined list of keywords to worker method?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function using `Pool`. You can pass text and keyword_list and it will work. You could use `Pool.starmap` to pass tuples of `(text, keyword)`, but you would need to deal with an iterable that had 10k references to `text`.

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool

def search_worker(text, keyword):
    return int(keyword in text)

def parallel_search_text(text, keyword_list):
    processes = 4
    chunk_size = 10
    total = 0
    func = partial(search_worker, text)
    with Pool(processes=processes) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(func, keyword_list, chunksize=chunk_size):
            total += result

    return total

if __name__ == '__main__':
    texts = []  # a list of texts
    keywords = []  # a list of keywords
    for text in texts:
        print(parallel_search_text(text, keywords))
```

There is overhead in creating a pool of workers. It might be worth timeit-testing this against a simple single-process text search function.  Repeat calls can be sped up by creating one instance of `Pool` and passing it into the function.

```
def parallel_search_text2(text, keyword_list, pool):
    chunk_size = 10
    results = 0
    func = partial(search_worker, text)

    for result in pool.imap_unordered(func, keyword_list, chunksize=chunk_size):
        results += result
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    texts = []  # a list of texts
    keywords = []  # a list of keywords
    for text in texts:
        print(parallel_search_text2(text, keywords, pool))
```

Answer (score 0):

User `e.s` resolved the main problem in his comment but I'm posting a solution to `Om Prakash`'s comment requesting to pass in:

> both article and pre-defined list of keywords to worker method

Here is a simple way to do that. All you need to do is construct a tuple containing the arguments that you want the worker to process:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def search_worker(article_and_keyword):
    # unpack the tuple
    article, keyword = article_and_keyword

    # count occurrences
    score = 0
    if keyword in article:
        score += 1

    return score

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # the article and the keywords
    article = """The multiprocessing package also includes some APIs that are not in the threading module at all. For example, there is a neat Pool class that you can use to parallelize executing a function across multiple inputs."""
    keywords = ["threading", "package", "parallelize"]

    # construct the arguments for the search_worker; one keyword per worker but same article
    args = [(article, keyword) for keyword in keywords]

    # construct the pool and map to the workers
    with Pool(3) as pool:
        result = pool.map(search_worker, args)
    print(result)
```

If you're on a later version of python I would recommend trying `starmap` as that will make this a bit cleaner.