# python multiple processing using pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a assignment for my course in Python.

The question is this :

You will write a program creating multiple processes (p=10). Each process will receive
integer value (y) and compute y multiplying by 4 (y*4). A collection of y values is a list
of integers [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. You must use a process pool, so you need to map these 10
processes to take the list of y integers. Do the following:

Your program should print out the following three.
(1) Print out the original list.
(2) Print each running process name and its output of y*4 in random order of
execution

Output of (1):
Input list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Output of (2):
Output in random order:

PoolWorker-10 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20]

PoolWorker-11 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20]

PoolWorker-12 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20]

My first attempt was:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process
def f(number):
    result=4*number
    Process_name=current_process().name
    print(f"Poolworker -{Process_name} output: {result} ")

    return result

if __name__=='__main__':
    p= Pool(processes=10)
    numbers=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
    result=p.map(f,numbers)
```

The output was:

```html
Poolworker -SpawnPoolWorker-2 output: 0 
Poolworker -SpawnPoolWorker-2 output: 4 
Poolworker -SpawnPoolWorker-2 output: 8 
Poolworker -SpawnPoolWorker-2 output: 12 
Poolworker -SpawnPoolWorker-2 output: 16 
Poolworker -SpawnPoolWorker-2 output: 20
```

My second attempt:

```html
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process
def f(*number):
 numbers=list(number)
 i=0
 for x in numbers:
  numbers[i]=4*numbers[i]
  i+=1
 Process_name=current_process().name
 print(f"Poolworker -{Process_name}output: {numbers} ")

 return numbers

if __name__ == '__main__':
  array=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
  p=Pool(processes=10)
 
  result=p.map(f,array)
```

I still have the wrong output with the changes.

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: You might find this useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162230/how-to-share-data-between-all-process-in-python-multiprocessing

Comment: i was really having hard time with this so maybe i was ranting a lot sorry . and also im not native at english. having hard time to explain in english :/

Comment: The question is fine imo.

Comment: @JohnColeman fair comment.. I made some edits :)

Comment: @ johnashu  thx haha. i think i was inapproriate asking question like that . just too much stress from my hw

Comment: @sushisonjderekDon't worry about it.. We have all been there.. Good luck in your studies!

Comment: @johnashu  good luck to you too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `f` is applied to *each* number in your list whereas you want every worker to do the calculations on the *whole* list. Made some minor modifications to your code in order to get those results.

```
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process

def f(numbers):
    result= [4 * num for num in numbers]
    name=current_process().name
    print(f"Poolworker - {name} output: {result} ")
    return result

if __name__=='__main__':
    WORKERS = 10
    p = Pool(processes=WORKERS)
    numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    print(f"Original - {numbers}")
    result = p.map(f, repeat(numbers, WORKERS))
```

This returns the following:

```
Original - [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Poolworker - ForkPoolWorker-1 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20] 
Poolworker - ForkPoolWorker-2 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20] 
Poolworker - ForkPoolWorker-3 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20] 
Poolworker - ForkPoolWorker-4 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20] 
Poolworker - ForkPoolWorker-5 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20] 
Poolworker - ForkPoolWorker-6 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20] 
Poolworker - ForkPoolWorker-7 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20] 
Poolworker - ForkPoolWorker-8 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20] 
Poolworker - ForkPoolWorker-9 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20] 
Poolworker - ForkPoolWorker-10 output: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
```

Comment: i'd really appreciate ! but there's a few thing i couldn't understand .[4 * num for num in numbers] does this mean multiplying whole array elements? (idk much about python.) and also,  result = p.map(f, repeat(numbers, WORKERS))  in this pool map , it has 'repeat' . does it mean repeating 10times ?

Comment: `[4 * num for num in numbers]` is known as a list-comprehension so yes it is multiplying every number in the list by `4`. `repeat` is a function in the standard library which takes an iterable and repeats it `n` times where the user provides `n`. in our case we want it to repeat the number of times we have a process so we use that number as the argument

Comment: thanks a lot. i think i could understand ur answer easily .

Answer (score 1):

From your description you want all processes to multiply array by 4.

So use parallel processes that are each given an array of numbers to multiply.

[Reference](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html)

**Code**

```
from multiprocessing import Process

import multiprocessing as mp

def f(numbers, output):
    " Places process name and numbers multiplied by 4 into output queue "
    output.put((mp.current_process().name, [4*n for n in numbers]))

# Define an output queue
output = mp.Queue()

# Setup a list of processes that we want to run
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
processes = [mp.Process(target=f, args=([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], output)) for x in range(10)]

# Run processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()

# Exit the completed processes
for p in processes:
    p.join()

# Get process results from the output queue
results = [output.get() for p in processes]


for id, values in results:
  print(f'PoolWorker {id} output: {values}')
```

**Output**

```
PoolWorker Process-1 output: [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
PoolWorker Process-3 output: [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
PoolWorker Process-9 output: [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
PoolWorker Process-6 output: [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
PoolWorker Process-7 output: [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
PoolWorker Process-5 output: [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
PoolWorker Process-4 output: [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
PoolWorker Process-8 output: [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
PoolWorker Process-2 output: [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
PoolWorker Process-10 output: [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
```