# Best Practice to share Data between two Python Processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I started a new project quite recently it is about processing huge amounts of Data .The Data is read from a file and should be inserted into a Database and at the same time there are some calculation that are done on the Data. Therefor i designed a system for starting each of those task in one process. But i need to share the Data in Realtime between those processes i designed the system with the

```
multiprocessing.Manager()
```

and pass all shared variables as arguments to functions i execute.
Now im running in some issues because the Database cannot read the variable because the Read Task is always occupying the variable.
Im stuck right now because i don't find any proper solution to adress this issue

Thanks for all answers in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share data between Python processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157367/how-to-share-data-between-python-processes)

Comment: There are too many details missing to be able to answer your question. What's a hig amount of data? What amount of processing is required? What data rates are you expecting? What latencies must be achieved? Which database? What type of data is it?

Comment: You'll probably want to use a queue but the description of the problem is a bit vague